# Displaying quicklaunch in SharePoint-Hosted apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, apps-development

I wanted to create a SharePoint-Hosted app with custom navigation bar on the left side (like Quicklaunch). As far as I read, one way to do it effectively is to create a custom masterpage with the navigation included in it. The problem is - what about lists? How to create side navigation that would be visible both on lists and on my custom aspx pages across the SharePoint-Hosted app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. We can achieve it by injecting a static HTML (which we can get from an already rendered Quicklaunch) into the "sideNavBox" div using jQuery.

Comment: I have the same problem but I do not understand your solution. Can you please post some more details ?

Comment: @Tom It's been some time since I posted it but I'll try :) From what I remember, SharePoint Hosted Apps does not have support for the OOTB quick launch in the app web. However, the masterpage used by default still has the div with id `sideNavBox` in it (it's empty though). What you can do is to render the QL menu somewhere outside the app, copy the rendered HTML from the _#sideNavBox_ div and inject it into the same div in your app web using some JavaScript code.